# Add rows to existing UITableView section

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

I am trying to get some sample code on how I would add rows to an existing `UITableView`. I am trying to use the `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:` function.

```
    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:addindexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

Any ideas how these indexes work and how I can add to an existing section or, if I don't have a section, then create a new section?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to create an array of indexpaths as -

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
```

for example if you want to insert 2nd row in section 0 and already have 1 row in section 0 then create an index path for row 1 in section 0 and call the insertRowsAtIndexPaths on table view, it will insert 2nd row in section.

If there is no section in table view then you should use an int for data source to give no of sections in table view, in this use -

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return noOfSection; //here section is as int which is initially zero
}
```

and initially your int "noOfSection" will be zero then there will be no section in table, then when you want to add section increase your int value by 1 and call `[tableView reloadData];`

Answer (score 6):

You need to handle these functions if you are gonna insert row and section in a table view.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return noOfSections;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[noOfRows objectForIndex:section] intValue];
}
```

also if you are updating your table view it is recommended that you use beginUpdates and endUpdates method.

this is how you insert new row and section.

```
noOfSections++;
[self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:3] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];


// update your array before calling insertRowsAtIndexPaths: method
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:2]] 
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

check the sample code provided by the apple.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html