# Add a row to a TableView

Tags: objective-c, nstableview

I have an NSMutable array  and it is empty, I have a table view . A user clicks on an add button and I want the table view to highlight the next available row with the standard blinking courser. After the user clicks off focus, I want the row to be added to the array and the table to reload data. I know how to manipulate the array and redraw the view, but I don't know which methods exist for me to query the table row for input or to create a highlighted cell ready for edit.

If someone could help me that would be great.
Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `-tableView:insertRowsAtIndexPaths` to add rows (and you can even add them with different animations):

[Add rows to existing UITableView section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906683/add-rows-to-existing-uitableview-section)