# UITableView Data Inconsistency

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` backed by a `NSArray`.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return self.data.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

  }
  id item = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.item = item;

  return cell;
}
```

Very standard. Now the problem is that `reloadData` will ask for `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRows` synchronously, but will call `cellForRow` asynchronously. So sometimes, by the time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called, the data array has changed, and so `[self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` gets an out of bounds exception and crashes the app. How do I avoid this?

Note that every time I set the `data` array, I also call `[self.tableView reloadData]`.

Comment: do you know how many rows you are supposed to have when the application crashes? and do you know what the values of [data count] and indexPath.row are when it crashes?

Comment: How often do you change the array?

Comment: @pro_metedor Every time this feed is refreshed, a cached version (if available) is returned first, followed shortly by the source version. Both callbacks set the data array and call reloadData.

Comment: @Kyle the exact numbers vary, but because it asks for the cells in order, it always crashes when indexPath.row = data.count.

Answer (score 0):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called frequently, (on scroll etc), you could just add a simple line of code to check if the size of the data array is smaller than the cell being requested. Although this means you might end up with blank cells.

I'd set breakpoints on both methods, right click the breakpoints -> "edit breakpoint" and tick "automatically continue after evaluating". Then click "add action" -> "debugger command" and then type "po data" or "po [data count]".

This will print information about the array in the debug console every time the breakpoint is hit (without stopping). You should then be able to look through the debug output and see where it is falling out of sync. Add some `NSLog` statements to to tell you which method is is being called etc and work from there.

Comment: I am well aware of why it can fall out of sync, I just don't know how to fix the rare times when the `data` array gets changed again before `cellFoRow` is done.

Comment: the first step would be to pinpoint the times it does happen, and try to work out why that's happening, and try to pin it down to reproducible conditions, with out being able to test your code base it's very hard to say why it's happening

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to avoid such a situation is to avoid user interaction while data is updated.May be you can show a screen to user that "updating.." and an activity indicator.

Another way is that to have another array to populate new data, handling can be done in separate thread  and at times only it is assigned back to the datasource array with reloading call after that.There also a screen with same can be used while datasource array gets changed

Comment: you don't have to touch the screen for this crash to occur. it happens because by the time `cellForRow` gets called, the underlying `data` array has been modified, by for example, at network request returning.

Answer (score 0):

Quick hack I used, try this and see if it works for you:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

  }

  // -----------------------------------------------------------------
  // the magical line that prevents the table from fetching the data
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------
  if([indexPath row] < [self.data count])
  {

      id item = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      cell.item = item;
  }

  return cell;
}
```

:D

Comment: lol id rather not fix it like this, though ill be sure to use this as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

You should store a local array, that doesnt get modified. then, when your base array changes, you can update your storred array safely. Look into adding/removing cells from a table view using the built in api [Add rows to existing UITableView section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906683/add-rows-to-existing-uitableview-section)